# eclipselink and weblogic12g CLOB ClassCastException

Tags: oracle, eclipselink, classcastexception, weblogic12c, lob

I have an application deployed in a Weblogic 12g, and a datasource configured against an oracle RAC.
It uses as JPA provider; EclipseLink 2.4.1.

The problem is this exception;

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-3001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob_oracle_sql_CLOB@87a98a], of class [class weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob_oracle_sql_CLOB], could not be converted to [class java.lang.String].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.CLOB

....

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.CLOB
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob_oracle_sql_CLOB.length(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToString(ConversionManager.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObject(ConversionManager.java:100)

....
```

Well, I understand what is the problem but **I can't understand why only occurs when some Oracle instance in the Oracle RAC was reset.** When this occurs, the only thing to do is restart the WLS instance. ah! While I have this error, the rest of the datatypes work well!.

Maybe there are some kind of direct relaction between LOB types and instances of Oracle servers inside a RAC? It's possible some kind of scenario that restarting an Oracle instance inside a RAC the CLOB datatypes don't works?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards

Comment: Odd that this is happening within the WLS wrapper class - it should know it has a CLOB instance and what it is.  Seems like it must be a classloader issue where the clob instance was loaded on a different loader.

Comment: Thanks Chris,

but one thing to take in account in ths strange problem is that it  only occurs when one instance of the oracle RAC is reseted. If the problem's cause were about classloadings the problem would occurs more times and not just when one instance is reseted.

I'm afraid that there some kind of relation between connections, clob's and oracle instances...

More details about the config is that the Datasource configured in Weblogic 12c Server is a GEneric Type with URI aimed to SCAN adress.